# What is the proper way to validate email uniqueness with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cannot find a proper way to provide validation for email uniqueness in mongoose.  Nothing I have found actually works.  I was thinking to use Schema.pre, but how would I go about writing the code for that if that is the case?  The Mongoose documentation is very poor and does not describe how or what pre does.

I would appreciate it if somebody could tell me how this is normally done or point me in the right direction.  I don't understand why something so simple has no simple solution in mongoose...

Comment: Couldn’t you just define the field as unique and case insensitive/force lowercase?

Comment: @Joe [The `unique` option for schemas is not a validator. It's a convenient helper for building MongoDB unique indexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator)

Comment: oh you're attempting to build something to determine if it's actually an email address, got it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [custom validator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators):

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: async function(email) {
        const user = await this.constructor.findOne({ email });
        if(user) {
          if(this.id === user.id) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      message: props => 'The specified email address is already in use.'
    },
    required: [true, 'User email required']
  }
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is perfect.  I have seen examples of using validators, however, I was hesitant to copy and paste because I don't like to use code that I don't understand.  This I actually understand.

Comment: Quick question though, what is 'this' referring to?  The Schema?  And then 'this.constructor' would be the actual model?  Is that correct?

Comment: [`this` refers to the document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#types-of-middleware) and yes `this.constructor` would be the actual model

Comment: This answer must be updated, because this line must be return Boolean(!user);
Otherwise if the email is not found, it will return false, causing problem.

Comment: How can I convert the above to arrow function?  I was trying to use  validator: async(email) => {
        const user = await usersSchema.findOne({ email });  but it says that findOne is not a property of usersSchema

Comment: @greatTeacherOnizuka [#3619](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3619), [#3695](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3695)

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to check email uniqueness in the register route.

This way we can fully control which status code or error message should be sent to the client.

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) return res.status(400).send("User already registered.");

    user = new User({ email, password });
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    await user.save();

    res.send("registered");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a neat way to implement.

Comment: You're using a try/catch, would be better to throw exception if user found and not return the 400 in the try, the catch is only there to catch any other errors that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

##### Multiple Custom Validations

For running multiple validation checks on your email field, you will need to throw Error objects with different messages for each validation.

In this example, I specify 3 different validation checks, including uniqueness, with 3 different custom error messages, but you can add as many checks as you need.

```js
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "An email address is required."],
    validate: validateEmail,
  },
})

async function validateEmail(email) {
  if (!isEmail(email)) throw new Error("Please enter a valid email address.")
  const user = await this.constructor.findOne({ email })
  if (user) throw new Error("A user is already registered with this email address.")
}
```

First, the `required` check runs, and if empty, returns the first validation message.

Second, pass a function to the `validate` field.  In this function, the `email` is passed as a parameter.  `isEmail` can be any type of function that checks that a string is the proper email format.  If it fails, specify the error message with a new Error object

To validate the uniqueness with mongoose, run the `findOne` query from the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212354/13222359) and if a user is returned, then throw error with that validation text.

**Notes**

- It is not necessary to return `true` or `false` from these functions. Simply throw an error *IF* the validation fails and let the function resolve naturally.
- It is important that you do not try to pass an arrow function to the `validate` property, as you need the lexically scoped `this` available in the function execution.
- The answer above is correct, however doesn't solve for the issue of needing to run additional checks besides required and unique, and send custom error messages for each.

Answer (score 0):

All the above responses work, but lack optimization:

```
import type {Types} from 'mongoose';

const emailRegExp = new RegExp(/^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/);

export const isEmail = {
    validator: (email: string): boolean => emailRegExp.test(email),
    message: 'INVALID_EMAIL',
}

export const emailIsUnique = {
    async validator(email: string): Promise<boolean> {
        const model = this.constructor as Model<any>;
        const id = this._id as Types.ObjectId;
        const user = await model.exists({email}).exec();

        return user === null || this._id.equals(user._id);
    },
    message: 'ALREADY_USED_EMAIL',
};

const userSchema = new Schema<User, Model<User>, User>({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [isEmail, emailIsUnique],
    }
});

const userModel = model('User', userSchema);
```

From top to bottom:

- It's a `TypeScript` version so just remove type annotations for pure JS.
- I've included a simple regex pattern for the email but you can use the pattern you want.
- I'm using two separated validators for readability and to be able to use one without the other if I need to.
- I'm using `RegExp.prototype.test()` for performance concern and because the return value is already a boolean.
- I'm using `exists()` to just retrieve the useful bits I need: the `_id`. [see doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-exists)
- If a user is found the later condition make sure that it's not an update to avoid **false positive**.
- The schema definition is also important: `unique: true` provide a useful unique index on email key for a faster search when using `findOne()`. It will also throw if the email we try to add to the index is duplicated, **but be careful it's not real a validator**. [see doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-unique-option-is-not-a-validator)
- `lowercase: true` is also important to avoid case comparison troubles (**false negative**)

Hope this little snippet will help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");

// creating schema for collection oof user.......
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength:3
    },
    phone:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:10,
        unique: true,
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
        validate: validateEmail,
    }
});

  
// creating document
const User = new mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

async function validateEmail(email) {
    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) throw new Error("Please enter a valid email address.")
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })
    if (user) throw new Error("A user is already registered with this email address.")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just amending the answer from SuleymanSah, use the try/catch instead of returning 400 response code in the try.

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
       throw new Error("User already registered!");
    }

    user = new User({ email, password });
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    await user.save();

    res.send("registered");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```